# Have access in Future.sequence to object that contains Future

Tags: scala

I have the following function in Scala:

```
object TestFutures5 extends App {

  def future (i:Int) = Future { i * 10 }
  var rnd = scala.util.Random

  val futureResult = (1 to 10).map {
     x =>
       val y = rnd.nextInt(x)
      (future(x),y)  // <- this should return a future 
                     // as it needs to be processed by Future.sequence
   }

   Future.sequence(futureResult).foreach(list => println(list)) // <- this does not compile


  Thread.sleep(5000)
}
```

In `Future.sequence` function I need to have access to the result of `future(x)` and to each variable `y`, but since `sequence` works only with futures this code does not compile. How to refactor/fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just add `y` to the result of the future:

```
future(x).map(res => (res, y))
```

Your sequence will now contain a list of tuples with the result and the value of `y`

Answer (score 1):

use `traverse`

```
Future.traverse(futureResult)(pair => pair._1.map(result => (pair._2, result)))
```

map each future so that the result will have `y` value.

```
Future.traverse(futureResult)(pair => pair._1.map(result => (pair._2, Right(result))).recover { case th => (pair._2, Left(th)) })
```

To get the `y` value in case of failure use recover.

So, to summarize it. You are using `y` as a tag or index for your future computation so that you can know what future with tag failed.

`y` works as a tag or name to the future.

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> Future.traverse(futureResult)(pair => pair._1.map(result => (pair._2, Right(result))).recover { case th => (pair._2, Left(th)) })
result: scala.concurrent.Future[scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, scala.util.Either[Throwable,Int])]] = Future(<not completed>)
```